# Migracion de una Base de datos Oracle a SQL Server con el SQL Server Migration Assistant

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Estoy intentando migrar una base de datos Oracle a SQL Server con el SQL Server Migration Assistant. Cree el proyecto y luego cuando me conecte a mi bases de datos Oracle recolecto toda la informacion y se trajo todos los esquemas. Habra alguna manera de que solo se traiga el esquema perteneciente al usuario o a juro se trae todos los esquemas. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible y está [documentado](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313198(v=sql.110).aspx), de hecho puedes elegir manualmente que objetos importar, si tampoco quieres importar todo un esquema completo.

Una vez te has conectado a Oracle desde la herramienta, utiliza el *Oracle metadata explorer* para seleccionar qué quieres importar y qué no:

[image: oracle metadata explorer]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si, pero la pregunta mia es habra alguna manera de antes de conectarme a oracle de decirle quiero que me traiga solo el esquema perteneciente al usuario en cuestion y no que me traiga todos los esquemas porque imaginemos por un momento de hecho me esta ocurriendo tengo una base de datos con aprox 500 esquemas, que ocurre? cuando el trata de recolectar los datos se queda sin memoria porque obviamente imaginemos que cada esquema tenga 100 tabla y cada tabla 20 millones de registros.

Comment: @Julio, eso no quedaba claro con tu pregunta, pero es sencillo, en ese caso: conéctate a Oracle con un usuario que tenga permisos solo sobre el esquema que te interesa migrar. La herramienta traerá todo lo que esté visible para el usuario con el que te conectas, no más que eso. Edito mi respuesta para hacerlo claro.

Comment: perdon por no haber escrito bien la pregunta. El detalle que veo es que el SSMA pide como requisitos ciertos privilegios que debe tener el usuario: SELECT ANY TABLE, SELECT ANY DICTIONARY, CREATE ANY PROCEDURE, SELECT ANY SEQUENCE, CREATE ANY TYPE, CREATE ANY TRIGGER. Pienso que con estos privilegios dicho usuario puede ver cualquier esquema y por ende se va a traer todos los esquemas por default

Comment: ¿Qué privilegios pide?

Comment: los comente arriba

Comment: perdon por no haber escrito bien la pregunta. El detalle que veo es que el SSMA pide como requisitos ciertos privilegios que debe tener el usuario: SELECT ANY TABLE, SELECT ANY DICTIONARY, CREATE ANY PROCEDURE, SELECT ANY SEQUENCE, CREATE ANY TYPE, CREATE ANY TRIGGER. Pienso que con estos privilegios dicho usuario puede ver cualquier esquema y por ende se va a traer todos los esquemas por default

Comment: Julio, no tengo oracle a mano para probar ahora, pero en ese caso, me temo que las opciones se limitan. Es una migración de una vez? Si es así, podrías hacer un dump de ese esquema y levantarlo en otra instancia. Si no, las opciones se van reduciendo, por ahora no se me ocurren muchas otras.

Answer (score 0):

With this tool you can do the migration:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/migrate/guides/oracle-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: 1. ¡Estás en [es.so]! 2. El contenido esencial del enlace debe ir _en la respuesta_. Si el enlace llega a caer, volverá inválida a esta respuesta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.